# Node.JS, Electron: BrowserWindow Outside ready

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I'm trying to define new instance of `BrowserWindow` before `ready` state, example:

```
var authWindow = new BrowserWindow({ width: 800, height: 600, show: false, 'node-integration': false });
```

And as i expected, i got an error:

**Error: Cannot create BrowserWindow before app is ready**

I need to specify it before `app.on('ready')` (probably there is another way) because i need to have defined `authWindow` variable for this callbacks:

```
authWindow.webContents.on('did-get-redirect-request, function (event, oldUrl, newUrl) {
handleCallback(newUrl)
  })
```

I know i can put all this into `app.on('ready')` callback function, but it becomes messy and i don't think this is the right way of doing so.

Comment: Your window is not going to be getting any redirect requests before the app is ready....so I don't know see what the problem is. Follow the canonical electron way and you'll be fine. :)

Comment: @ccnokes, the problem is that it is Not main window... And if I need to create a bunch of those my ready function becomes really messy